# How to use a (skylo) loader when navigating between views in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Just started using a template with my asp.net mvc 5 project that comes bundled with the [skylo extension for Bootstrap](https://github.com/colintoh/skylo). I was wondering what the correct way of implementing this was, so that it is always displaying a loader when navigating between views. Should it be implemented in the master layout or is this something that goes into each view?

How can I actually figure out how much there is to load and match the progress of the bar to this? Is this something ajax can handle or are there other ways?

Sorry for the 'how do I do this' question, but I really can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Hi Nicklas, I designed skylo to be used for ajax application where there are no page refresh.

As for "how to match the load with the progress", I will say it's all up to you. If i have 3 ajax request for API, I will divide the progress to be 33% each. So each successful ajax call will add 33% to the progress bar. After I received the last successful API call, i will trigger the skylo "end" method to wrap up everything.

Comment: Thanks @p0larBoy! Will have a look into it when doing heavy operations :)